# can we use this code for bulk data

Tags: trigger

```
trigger postOnAcc on Opportunity (after insert) 
{
    List<FeedItem> posts = new List<FeedItem>();          //create a list to hold post
    Set<Id> oppSet=new Set<Id>();                     //create a list to hold new opportunity
    for(Opportunity opp:Trigger.new)                    //Iterate for loop on new opportunity
    {
        oppSet.add(opp.AccountId);                    //add opportunity account id in opportunity list
    }
    if(oppSet.size() >0)                          //check there is an opportunity in oppSet
    {
        for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.New)               //Iterate loop for new opp
        {

            if(opp.AccountId != null)    //check opportunity accountid is not null
            {
                FeedItem post = new FeedItem();    //adding a text post
                Post.ParentId = opp.AccountId;
                post.body = 'New Opportunity is created with Opportunity Id - '+opp.Id + ' and Opportunity name is equal to - '+opp.Name;
                posts.add(post);          //add post in posts List
            }
         }

    }
    insert posts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No growth in the number of queries or DMLs (insert/update/delete) per trigger row is the core bulkification need, so the answer is "yes".

Comment: my code is correct or not?

Comment: @Michael From the bulkification viewpoint, yes your code appears correct.

Comment: @Michael Keith is correct, but note that half of your code is not necessary. oppSet will never have size 0, and you never use it for anything, so you have at least 9 lines of code you don't need in your trigger.